# Tcpdump write pcap to remote server with file rotation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcpdump

I'm trying to run tcpdump on linux machine, which needs to write pcap on the remote server with file rotation every 10 seconds.

```
tcpdump -s0 -i eth0 -G 10 -w - | ssh {remote_ip} "cat > capture_%d-%m_%Y__%H_%M.pcap"
```

The file gets return on the remote server for first cycle (10 seconds) and then I'm getting the following error.

```
tcpdump: listening on ens224, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
tcpdump: Can't write to standard output: Bad file descriptor
```

I'm using `-G` for time based rotation, if I remove `-G`, then i'm able to write to remote server continuously.

*My remote server is configured with password-less login form this host.*

Comment: U could try: ` ... | ssh user@dest /bin/sh <<<'cat > destfile'

Comment: You can't use rotation with `-w -`, because it needs to be able to create an output file with the timestamp in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe tcpdump to another tcpdump so in your case :

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w - not port 22 | \
     ssh my.remote.host tcpdump -r - -w /tmp/capture_%d-%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S.pcap  -G 2 -C 100
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks @EchoMike444